# SQL error using MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm trying to read datafrom the MySQL database.  I'm getting the following error message:

```
2011   1   21333333
2011   2   13500000
2011   3   17285714
2011   4   15500000
2011   5   15800000
2011   6   15900000
2011   7   15875000
2011   8   15600000
2011   9   17666666
2011   10   20000000
2011   11   15958333
2011   12   21583333
2012   1   21519230
2012   2   25450000
2012   3   21400000
2012   4   34166666
2012   5   27928571
2012   6   29250000
2012   7   17550000
2012   8   19111111
2012   9   18200000
2012   10   15181818
2012   11   14455555
2012   12   16900000
2013   1   13500000
2013   2   13600000
2013   3   12812500
java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set//and this one too
0   2.1333333E7    21333333
1   1.35E7    13500000
2   1.7285714E7    17285714
3   1.55E7    15500000
4   1.58E7    15800000
5   1.59E7    15900000
6   1.5875E7    15875000
7   1.56E7    15600000
8   1.7666666E7    17666666
9   2.0E7    20000000
10   1.5958333E7    15958333
11   2.1583333E7    21583333
12   2.151923E7    21519230
13   2.545E7    25450000
14   2.14E7    21400000
15   3.4166666E7    34166666
16   2.7928571E7    27928571
17   2.925E7    29250000
18   1.755E7    17550000
19   1.9111111E7    19111111
20   1.82E7    18200000
21   1.5181818E7    15181818
22   1.4455555E7    14455555
23   1.69E7    16900000
24   1.35E7    13500000
25   1.36E7    13600000
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:841)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2672)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2813)
    at system.HOME.avgr.makeAvg(avgr.java:104)
    at system.HOME.avgr.<init>(avgr.java:64)
    at system.HOME.avgr.main(avgr.java:164)
```

this are the codes for line 104 i have indicated by comment

```
public long[] makeAvg() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    Connection conn;
    ResultSet rs1;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT count( 'month' ) AS yt, `Month` , `Year` , avg( `asking_price` ) AS av FROM `tbl_p`WHERE `sale` LIKE 'S' AND b <7 and year between 2011 and 2013  GROUP BY `Year` , `Month` ORDER BY `tbl_p`.`year` ASC";
        conn = (Connection) DBConnection.getDBConnection();
        pstmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs1 = pstmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(count_of_set + "nmklnmkl");
        for (; count <= count_of_set; count++) {
            if (count == 0) {
                rs1.first();
                avgNumerator[count] = rs1.getInt("av");
                year[count] = rs1.getInt("year");
                month[count] = rs1.getInt("Month");
                System.out.println(year[count] + "   " + month[count] + "   " + avgNumerator[count]);
            } else {
                rs1.next();
                avgNumerator[count] = rs1.getInt("av");
                year[count] = rs1.getInt("year");
                month[count] = rs1.getInt("Month");
                System.out.println(year[count] + "   " + month[count] + "   " + avgNumerator[count]);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return avgNumerator;
}
```

Comment: You only tell us that you get a `java.sql.SQLException`. Please include more details.

Comment: Does count start at 0? Then `for (; count <= count_of_set;count++)` should be `for (; count < count_of_set;count++)`

Comment: I don't see the commented line 104... (though I assume it is the `rs1.next()` in the else block.)

Comment: yes it is true thatis line 104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using for loop to retrieve
use while loop this way

```
while(rs1.next())
{
//your code
}
```

As per your loop,when the last is row is completed still it tries to retrieve data.

Comment: How will this help with a `java.sql.SQLException`?

Comment: @Tichodroma The op is facing problem when the last row comes.So either while loop will work or ppteka_66 answer

Answer (score 1):

This line does smell cheesy:

```
for (; count <= count_of_set;count++){
```

If `count` starts from 0 (as the `if(count==0)` line would suggest), this tries to iterate `(count+1)` times...

This would fix the *immediate* problem:

```
for (; count < count_of_set;count++){
```

However, the *real solution* to the problem would be to use the JDBC API properly, as seen in the [answer of @javaBeginner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18784991/1667004)